# Updating a Button in an MS Access 2013 Form

Tags: ms-access-2013

I have a form in MS Access 2013 that is associated with two tables.  The form populates with various fields from each table.  I also have several buttons to Add a Record, Find a Record (from one of the tables), Save, and Close Form.  I want to add a button that allows me to find a record from the other table.  I was successfull creating the button, but the button is looking at the wrong table.  I want the button to look at the other table but I can't find a way to switch the table the button is looking at.  I don't understand Macros very well but this appears to be a very easy problem.  How can I make the button look at the right table?

Comment: afaik a form can be associated only with one table/query. So to have two tables you either have a sub-form or a query based on both tables. If you have sub-forms, try adding the button to the subform itself

Comment: Thank you.  I would like to say that my form does use two tables without a subform.  When I enter in a unique number for the record from one table, it populates the form.  Then I enter data into the form which populates different table.  I'm going to try using a query though to see if I can get the result I'm looking for.  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: You will have to rethink this unusual concept.